How can I evaluate a form dynamically?
I don't quite know how to ask this in English (which is my first language), so I'll try to illustrate.
I want to define an alist, which relates symbols to forms. I am not sure this is the right syntax, but something like this:
(defvar my-placeholders-alist
   (list
    '(a (lambda () ,asset-name))
    '(b (my-get-setting ,a-boolean-flag))
    '(c (my-get-other-setting))
    )
 )

And at runtime, I want to scan a string for placeholders, and replace each placeholder with ... the result of evaluating the cadr of the item in the alist at that time.
Something like
(let ((starting-string "%a %b")
      (a-boolean-flag t)
      (asset-name "foo"))
 (seq-reduce
  (lambda (acc cur)
    (let* ((key (car cur))
           (replaceable (concat "%" (symbol-name key)))
           (form-to-eval (cadr cur)))
      (if (s-contains? replaceable acc)
          (eval form-to-eval t)
        acc)))
  my-placeholders-alist
  starting-string)))
)

;; assuming (my-get-setting t) ==> "abc"

;; ==> "foo abc"

But I cannot figure out how to evaluate the form after lookup.
I've tried many options, combinations of funcall and eval and single quotes for the form, commas, .... I'm not clear on how to express what I want.
I could do this in JS or Java or C# but just do not know the elisp syntax.
Can anyone guide me?

eval is how you do that.  I haven't tried to understand the specifics of what you're doing though.  But as a trivial example: (eval '(+ 1 2)) => 3.

but (eval form-to-eval t) in my case is always resolving to (lambda () ,asset-name) .  It resolves to the lambda definition, not the result of evaluating the lambda. And of course the logical next step is (eval (eval form-to-eval t)) which gives me the same thing.  funcall is not quite right, because the value of the items in the alist is not always a function.  Maybe that is part of my problem.

Yes, evaluating a function definition defines a function.  If you want to evaluate a call to a function, the form you're evaluating has to be... a call to a function.  (eval '(func arg)) for instance.  Or (eval '(funcall funcvar arg) if the function is the value of funcvar.  Or (eval (funcall (lambda (x) ...) arg)) which is perhaps what you want.

Although if you wanted to evaluate a call to your example of (lambda () ,asset-name) you are surely better to just store and evaluate asset-name rather than wrapping a function around it.  At least if the value is self-evaluating, like a string is (which is my guess at what asset-name would be).  E.g. (eval "hello") => "hello"

thanks for this explanation.  but how would I "just store and evaluate" the symbol?
Syntax.
(defvar my-placeholders-alist (list '(a 'asset-name)  '(b (my-get-setting ,a-boolean-flag))) does not work.  asset-name is a symbol name here.  I want to evaluate what's stored in that symbol, at runtime.  Not at the time I define the alist.

Your data list is already quoted, so don't add another quote.  Just like you didn't need to quote the symbol a inside the quoted list, you don't need to quote the symbol asset-name inside the list.  Otherwise the form you're storing is (quote asset-name) which, when evaluated, just returns the symbol asset-name.

Based on our comments discussion, I suspect you wanted eval and this:
(defvar my-placeholders-alist
   (list
    '(a asset-name)
    '(b (my-get-setting ,a-boolean-flag))
    '(c (my-get-other-setting))))

I'm not sure what the , is expected to do in the second case, mind.  If you want a-boolean-flag to be evaluated when defining my-placeholders-alist then you need to backquote that form:
`(b (my-get-setting ,a-boolean-flag))

If you just want it to be evaluated when subsequently evaluating the call to my-get-setting, then you don't want a comma there at all.
I suspect you may really want something more like:
(defvar my-placeholders-alist
  '((a . asset-name)
    (b . (my-get-setting a-boolean-flag))
    (c . (my-get-other-setting))))

(cdr (assq 'b my-placeholders-alist)) => (my-get-setting a-boolean-flag)


yes, that all makes sense. And when I try it, it works, in the simple case.  Thanks.  I am still having trouble, in my case, in which I am trying to eval from within a lambda.  I don't understand the error.  I'm going to update my question, in case you still have appetite to help me out.

Actually, I am seeing the error, only in the case where I use edebug-defun. If I invoke my function without the debugger, it works.  Thanks for the guidance!
